# Video playback - libc / LibVLC crash on android

Tags: android, video, vlc, libc, libvlc

Im using LibVLC to play videos and my app crashes when seeking at videos' end with the following error:

`libc: ../../src/input/decoder.c:1331: DecoderPlayVideo: assertion "p_owner->b_first" failed`

Does anyone know what its about?

Thanks!

Comment: I Would like an answer to this as well. It happens sometimes when initializing a stream.

Comment: Did you found any help on this matter?

Comment: @JanCor take a look to my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for the issue!

Just compile VLC with "sh compile.sh release". With this release token a debug flag will be set to false and assertions will be ignored on c site.

I hope this helps others out of trouble!